# Как проверить валидность сторон треугольника в классе Triangle

Tags: python, ооп, исключения

Мне необходимо создать класс Triangle, который считает площадь треугольника и класс triangleNotValid для обработки исключения, если стороны треугольника не валидны.

```
class TriangleNotValid(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

class Triangle:
    
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides
        try:
            for item in self.sides:
                if (not isinstance(item, int) and not isinstance(item, float)):
                    raise TriangleNotValid("Not valid arguments")
        except TriangleNotValid as e:
            print(e)
    
    def get_area(self):
        a, b, c = self.sides
        p = (a + b + c) / 2
        area = (p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)) ** 0.5
        return area

not_valid_arguments = [
    ('3', 4, 5),
    ('a', 2, 3),
    (7, "str", 7),
    ('1', '1', '1'),
    'string',
    (7, 2),
    (7, 7, 7, 7),
    'str',
    10,
    ('a', 'str', 7)
]

for data in not_valid_arguments:
    try:
        Triangle(data)
    except TriangleNotValid as e:
        print(e)
```

Результат программы должен быть:

```
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
Not valid arguments
```

Но мой блок try...except не правильно работает и когда дохожу в проверке до 10 в not_valid_arguments появляется ошибка, что int не итерируемый объект.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых у вас не описан класс `TriangleNotValidArgumentException` и ошибка будет уже сразу в этом.

Во-вторых прежде чем делать перебор `for item in self.sides:` нужно проверить, что `self.sides` - это `Iterable`, точно так же через `isinstance` как вы делаете проверку внутри цикла и выбросить ваше кастомное исключение, если это не так. Когда на вход приходит просто число `10`, то вот этот перебор и ломается.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
...
if not isinstance(self.sides, Iterable):
    raise TriangleNotValid("Not valid arguments")
```

Comment: c наименованием класса поправил в описании

Comment: @Владимир Ну `Argument` ещё ладно, а вот `Exception` убирать из названия не нужно было, исключения должны иметь `Exception` в названии, такое соглашение.

Comment: from collections.abc import Iterable проверяет итерируемый объект или нет ?

Comment: Ладно, дописал ещё код, раз так непонятно )